# Jenkins Git Changelog plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I am trying to use git changelog in the post build action in Jenkins I get an error saying Cannot find on classpath (changelog.mustache) or filesystem (/changelog.mustache).

Changelog.txt is the filename I have given to be written into.

Could you please help?

Also, is there a way I can write the changelog into an email from this plugin?

Comment: IF you can get the changelog file create, you should be able to attach the file with the [email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-Attachments)

Comment: Question: did you tick the box for "configure template here"? that seems to be the easiest why to get things working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure a template for changelog processing. The easiest way to achieve this is to check the checkbox "Configure template here" in the section "Create file". You can use the preconfigured template that gets visible when you enable that checkbox.

For details have a look at the plugin documentation at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin in section "File in Jenkins workspace".

If you don't enable any template definition then your mentioned error will appear.